# zmq_vmci not supported for QNX VM?

Tags: c, virtual-machine, zeromq

I have been messing around with ZMQ on QNX 6.6 Neutrino virtual machine in C. Just some simple req-rep and pub-sub programs.  I have gotten these to work on just a single VM and running each program in its own process.

```
//client
void *context = zmq_ctx_new ();
void *requester = zmq_socket (context, ZMQ_REQ);
zmq_connect (requester, "tcp://localhost:8001");

//server
void *context = zmq_ctx_new ();
void *responder = zmq_socket (context, ZMQ_REP);
zmq_bind (responder, "tcp://*:8001")
```

However, when I change the transport from tcp to vmci, I get an error message of it not being supported.

> **Error message:** Protocol not configured or not supported.

My host machine is Windows 7. 
I am using VMware Workstation to host the VMs.
My libzmq version is 4.2.0.

Thanks for any help. :)

Comment: You might have already noticed, StackOverflow Community encourages users to post MCVE-complete examples, **incl.** the exact copy of Exceptions / Error messages one observes, so as to provide both relevant and reproducible scenario. Would you mind to update your post to include the complete details and also the error message? Thanks & Welcome Matt to this great Community of Knowledge

Answer (score 1):

### ZeroMQ vmci:// transport-class needs a few additional changes

beyond just a swap from `tcp:` to **`vmci:`** in the source code.

**`vmci://`** needs also to know ( receive ) a **`CID`** from VM-hypervisor.

```
//  Get, show and set the CID
cid       = VMCISock_GetLocalCID();
printf( "Obtained [%d] for using in vmci://<CID>:<port>", cid );
sprintf( aSockEndPOINT,            "vmci://%d:5555",      cid );

//  .bind()
opRetCode = zmq_bind( socket, aSockEndPOINT ); assert ( rc == 0 );
```

On the `.connect()` side:

```
//  --------------------------------------------------------------
//  .connect() using a CID
sprintf( aConnEndPOINT, "vmci://%d:5555", cid );
opRetCode = zmq_connect( socket, aConnEndPOINT ); assert ( rc == 0 );
```

Some other advice applicable for practicing ["wildcard"-**`bind()`**-s or for deferred **`VMCISock_GetLocalCID()`**-calls](http://api.zeromq.org/4-2:zmq-vmci)

---

### For QNX VM:

Could you confirm the QNX Neutrino has been successfully adapted to ZeroMQ?

**Location of Include File for C Programs**
the **`vmci_sockets.h`** include file in one of the  following locations:

Linux guests – **`/usr/lib/vmware-tools/include/vmci`**

Linux hosts – **`/usr/lib/vmware/include/vmci`**

---

Can you confirm, that your ZeroMQ QNX-port has been [generated by cross-building from FreeBSD port ( Chapter 2 )](http://zeromq.wdfiles.com/local--files/area:whitepapers/0MQonQNX.pdf) or by some other published approach to contain also **`vmci`**?

---

Did you test the VMCI for working on QNX side against the VMware Workstation in plain C ( without ZeroMQ )?

[May **enjoy a few scenarios to test** and POSACK / NACK the QNX / VMware Workstation **`vmci`-RTO state**.](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-55/topic/com.vmware.ICbase/PDF/ws9_esx55_vmci_sockets.pdf)

---

### Last but not least

The VM has to get due permissions to use the VMCI-services, otherwise the host / isolation takes prime:
[image]